# Complexity of a algorithm thats iterates based on the max number in an array?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

so I was doing a competitive programming challenge a friend proposed to me, and I was able to figure it out, but after that, I decided to have a bit of fun with other ways of solving it.

Thing is, I did find a weird way of doing it, but we can't really wrap our head around the complexity, because we think that it might not have a formal complexity?

A brief explanation of the problem is this:

You have an array ( might not be ordered ) of integers, all positive and bigger than 0.

Your task is to tell me the first integer that is missing from the array, so for example:

[1, 4, 5,3, 2, 6, 10] ==> The answer is 7

My fun way of doing it was:

You iterate through the array once, and put all the values in a HashMap, saving the max value in the array in a separate variable.

After that, you create a for loop that goes from 1 to the max value of the array.

Then you check if the for loop index exists in the hashmap, if it doesn't then you have found your answer.

The thing is, this would be O(n), but the for loop is screwing with me a bit.. Is it O(n)? 
It feel wrong to say it O(n).

Imagine this pseudo-code:

let numArray = {1, 2, 3, 1000};

```
for i=1 TO max(numArray){
     print "Hello there buddy"
}
```

What would the complexity of this be? Does it even have a formal complexity?

From my understanding, saying it has a complexity doesn't really follow the purpose of the Big O Notation, since the it's purpose is evaluating the time it's gonna take for some code to run, has the SIZE of the input changes, and here it doesn't matter the size of the input, just the value of the max number... If the array has 3 elements, and the max is 1 billion, it's still gonna take 1 billion iterations...

So, is there a specific notation for this?

How would you describe this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, we assume a new variable m and say that this solution is of `O(m)`, where m will be the highest number in the array; rather than saying `O(n)`.

Just an additional input, another better way to solve this problem is below:

assume

```
a = [1, 4, 5,3, 2, 6, 10]
for i in 0->n:
  if (a[i] < n)
    a[a[i]] = -a[a[i]];

for i in 0->n:
  if (a[i] > 0)
    print (i);
```

Basically the idea here is to mark visited index by reversing its sign to -ve.
While re-iterating first found positive element's index will be the missing item.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer! Yeah I did do it inplace the first time, but the fun answer was me just messing around.

So the total complexity of my algorithm would be O(n) + O(m) ?

Comment: Nope. It always will be O(m) based on your solution, because n will become insignificant here as the largest number will always have a higher dependency.

Comment: But wait, it has two loops, the first one is based on the size of the array, and the second one is based on the largest value of the array, so wouldn't it be O(n) + O(m) ?